# Add values on SQL table more times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a file called `addtime_eu.php` that adds into a SQL table called `europe` a row containing some datas.

```
<?php
//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Connection to MySQL failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " Please contact an admin or refresh the page.";
  }

//Create MySQL connection

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","my_mk7vrlist");

//Store datas in the table
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `europe` (`Num`,`playername`,`Friendcode`,`Country`,`Skype`,`Twitter`,`Youtube`) VALUES ('7', '".$_POST['playername']."', '".$_POST['fcs']."', '".$_POST['regione']."', '".$_POST['skype']."', '".$_POST['twitter']."', '".$_POST['youtube']."')");


//Close connection
mysqli_close($con);

echo "<br><p align='center'>Your datas has been added!<p>";
?>
```

This php file is called when I click this button in a page:

```
<form action="addtime_eu.php" method="POST">
<p align="center"><input value="Send record" type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

When I click this button once, the script adds into the table a row. If I try the second time to click the button, it doesn't add anything.

What should I do? Do I have to change any SQL setting?

Comment: not sure why you are wrapping the table europe and the column names in quotes, that's not normal.   aside from that it looks like the code should insert a row every time as you have no SELECT statement to drive the INSERT.   You get any errors?

Comment: You are ridiculously open to SQL Injection, due to concatenating with `$POST[...]`.  You should be using prepared statements.  If you leave things as they are now, you _will_ be hacked by automated tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe 'Num' is a Primary Key and the Insert is failing due to the fact that you are always trying to insert the same value.

Comment: How could I auto-increase the numbers in 'Num'? +1 by the way

Comment: That was my first thought as well... I would assumed the user would have checked to see if any error message, yes what is your PK on the table?

Comment: oops, I thought you were using SQL SERVER.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi one way could be declaring `Num`as integer and use AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Thank you, answer accepted. It works what you said. But when I call `mysqli_query();`, in VALUES I split the 'Num' field without adding anything?

Comment: Yes, forget about it. Mysql takes care of it.

Comment: Your query will look like this: "INSERT INTO `europe` (`playername`,`Friendcode`,`Country`,`Skype`,`Twitter`,`Youtube`) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['playername']."', '".$_POST['fcs']."', '".$_POST['regione']."', '".$_POST['skype']."', '".$_POST['twitter']."', '".$_POST['youtube']."')"